# Azure Portal Error: Failed to start virtual machine 'xxxx'. Error: The Key Vault secret referenced with the URL 'xxxx' does not exist

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-keyvault, azureportal

I have deleted some Key Vaults from my resource manager after assuming that they are not used anywhere in my configuration and that those were some leftovers from my testing. Now I can't start my virtual machines and this error message appears.

> Failed to start virtual machine 'xxxx'. Error: The Key Vault secret
>   referenced with the URL 'xxxx' does not exist.

Could you please advise me how to put my virtual machines back on track since I can't afford the time building them again?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue except my SSL certificate needed to be renewed.  If you use https://resources.azure.com, you can see the old URL listed in the secrets property of the osProfile.

I couldn't update the new vault certificate with my ARM template so I had to fix it with Powershell first.  This removes the old vault so my template could add the new one.

```
$vaultName = "<your vault name>"
$vmName = "<your vm name>"
$rg = "<your resource group>"

$vaultId = (Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName $vaultName).ResourceId
$vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $vmName

Remove-AzVMSecret -VM $vm -SourceVaultId $vaultId
Update-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $rg -VM $vm
```

This worked for me so I wanted to document it in case it helps somebody else.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to recover multiple deleted vaults using Azure CLI. At the moment Azure keeps the deleted vault for 90 days.

**Azure CLI version: 2.0.68**

**Command:** az keyvault recover --location "your vault location" --resource-group "your vault resource group" --name "your vault name"

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you re-creating the VM with the existing VHD file.

I reproduce the same error in my lab. When I try to re-upload the certificate, I find that the GUID of this certificate has been changed. So we need to edit the configuration of the VM.

Then I find that the "windowsConfiguration.winRM.listeners" property can not be changed if the VM has been deployed. Therefore, in conclusion, you may need to recreate your VM with the same VHD file.

[image]